# Extending the YAML Reference tag (anchors and aliases)

Tags: syntax, yaml, alias, cross-reference

In Yaml we can reference another yaml node like:

```
Person: &PersonID
  FirstName: Xyz
  LastName: Abc

Type:
  - *PersonID
```

But if I want to extend this to :

```
Type:
  - *PersonID
     Foo: foo
Type1:
  - *PersonID
     Bar: bar
```

I cannot do this. I have a solution below but wanted to know is there a specific reason it doesn't work?

```
Type:
  - ReferenceType: *PersonID
    Age: 20
```

I know & and * are for YAML alias cross-references, but is there a better way to deal with this?

Answer (score 2):

Well, there is the [merge](http://yaml.org/type/merge.html) key which is supported by some implementations:

```
Person: &PersonID
  FirstName: Xyz
  LastName: Abc

Type:
  << : *PersonID
  Foo: foo
Type1:
  << : *PersonID
  Bar: bar
```

However, be aware that this is not part of core YAML and hasn't been updated for YAML 1.2, so your implementation may or may not support it.

The predominant opinion on this in the YAML community is that `<<` was a bad idea from the beginning and should not have been specified, for two reasons:

- It does not specify its interaction with non-core tags (what if the mapping where something should be merged into has some specific tag that does not allow `<<` as child? Is it valid? Is it invalid?).
- It implements an operation even though YAML is a data description language. That simply does not fit into YAML and also gives people the false impression that YAML supports such operations in general (but you cannot do the same for sequences etc).

It seems to fit your demands here, but if you use it, be aware of its shortcomings.

Comment: Huh. I had no idea `<<` had been abandoned. It makes sense, though.

Comment: There is no official statement. Just that the YAML type repository has not been updated for 1.2. We informally talked about it and came to the conclusion that it should be dropped in future versions.